# Regex return always false c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, forms

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$/i");

bool result = rgx.IsMatch("PPPPLT80R10M082K"); 

MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

This is a regex for italian tax code. It should works, I've also tried on regex101.com and it gives no error:
[image: See also here]
The problem is that when I run the code the result is always false. What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, your regex *pattern* works. Regex delimiters and the modifiers are not part of the pattern, and you should provide the pattern as the argument to the Regex constructor. Use `new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: BTW, regex101 does not support .NET regex.

Comment: Also make sure to test your regular expressions on a site that actually uses C# like http://regexstorm.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove surrounding `/` from your regex, there is no need for it in .NET.

Case insensitivity can be specified using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` second argument of `Regex` constructor.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{6}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```